# How to save the google vision API response to a handable file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to extract all the information that the google cloud vision OCR API offers to me from some tickets. I can save the text in a .txt but the rest of the response `response = client.text_detection(image=image)` I don't know how to save it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this tutorial [Quickstart: Using client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Then, assuming that you got the `response`, you can save it to a file using this code:

```
text_file = open("sample.txt", "w")
text_file.write(str(response))
text_file.close()
```

Finally I tested on console:

```
cat sample.txt

label_annotations {
  mid: "/m/01yrx"
  description: "Cat"
  score: 0.9895679950714111
  topicality: 0.9895679950714111
}
label_annotations {
  mid: "/m/0307l"
  description: "Felidae"
  score: 0.9541760087013245
  topicality: 0.9541760087013245
}
label_annotations {
  mid: "/m/01l7qd"
  description: "Whiskers"
  score: 0.953809380531311
  topicality: 0.953809380531311
}
label_annotations {
  mid: "/m/01k74n"
  description: "Facial expression"
  score: 0.9447915554046631
  topicality: 0.9447915554046631
}
```